# Global variable not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am building a small tool using Apps Script. I can't seem to get the global variable (URL) to update to include the docId.

What I expect

- Run the App function, which first creates a Google Doc and sets the global variable for the documentId (docId). Second it calls myOnClickhandler, which should take the global url variable that includes the updated docId.

What is happening:

- The variable 'url' in `myClickHandler` is not updated to the value of 'docId' set in the createProject function.

```
var docId = "";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + docId + "/";   
 

function doGet() {
      var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyUI');
      return output;
    }

function createProject(test="test"){
  const doc = DocumentApp.create(test);
  docId = doc.getId();// <-- Update global docId variable. Doesn't seem to be working. 
  Logger.log("Doc ID is: " + docId);
}

function myOnClickHandler(){
  const myList = ["Hello from the server", url]
  Logger.log("URL is: " + url);
}

function app(){
  createProject();
  myOnClickHandler();
}
```

Probably a simple mistake on my part, but I am banging my head against the wall on this one. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Your url string is built at the point the `url` variable is declared. Updating `docId` after `url` is initialized will not change the string.

Comment: Do you want to set the `url` variable after the docId variable is updated in the createProject() function? Then You have to add `url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + docId + "/";` to your createProject().

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, strings are [immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Immutable). Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of a static text string, like this:

```
let docId;
const getUrl_ = (docId) => `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${docId}/`;

function test() {
  docId = 'testString';
  const url = getUrl_(docId);
  console.log(url);
}
```